# Addin through a numpy array using indexes Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, iterator

I am trying to write a numpy function where it will add portions of the sequences of `indexes` value if the last element in the index if not equal to the `len(Numbers)`. So the length of `Numbers`is 14 and the last index value within `indexes` is 11, so since 11 is lower than 14 the while loop adds the first element to the sequence `3` to the end of the `indexes` array. `11+ 3= 14`, the updated version of `indexes` becoming `[0, 3 , 7, 11,14]`. The program checks again since the last index in `indexes= 14` and the last element in `Numbers` = 14 so it stops. The code down below is faulty how could I fix it?

```
Numbers = np.array([1, 5, 6,7,4,3,6,7,11,3,4,6,2,20])
indexes = np.array([0, 3 , 7, 11])

p= 1
while len(Numbers) > indexes[-1]:
    np.concatenate(indexes, indexes[p])
    p= p+ 1
    if p ==4:
        p = 1
```

Expected Output

```
indexes = [0, 3 , 7, 11,14]
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```py
import numpy as np


numbers = np.array([1, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 6, 7, 11, 3, 4, 6, 2, 20])
indexes = np.array([0, 3, 7, 11])

while numbers.shape[0] > indexes[-1]:
    diff = (numbers.shape[0] - indexes[-1]) + indexes[-1]
    indexes = np.append(indexes, diff)

print(indexes)
```

It is simplier than you thought.
Here `diff = (len(numbers) - indexes[-1]) + indexes[-1]` I check difference between `numbers` length and last element in `indexes` and add this difference to the last element in `indexes`
And here `diff = (len(numbers) - indexes[-1]) + indexes[-1]` I just append the resulting value to `indexes`